# Bind Combo Box based on another Combo Box's selected item - MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I currently have a Combo Box which is populated with Artist names and I need to bind it to another once the Artist is selected. These are set up as follows in my view:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,81,0,0" Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Artists}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArtist}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,115,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlbums}" Width="120" />
```

In my ViewModel I have the following:

```
private void initialiseArtists()
    {
        MusicDataClassesDataContext dataClasses = new MusicDataClassesDataContext();

        artistList = (from m in dataClasses.tblArtists select m.ArtistName).ToList();
    }

    public List<String> Artists
    {
        get
        {
            return this.artistList;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedArtist
    {
        set
        {
            this.selectedArtist = value;
            initialiseAlbums();
        }
    }

    private void initialiseAlbums()
    {
        if (selectedArtist != null)
        {
            MusicDataClassesDataContext dataClasses = new MusicDataClassesDataContext();

            var getArtist = dataClasses.tblArtists.FirstOrDefault(band => band.ArtistName == selectedArtist);
            albumList = (from album in dataClasses.tblAlbums
                         where album.ArtistID == getArtist.ArtistID
                         select album.AlbumName).ToList();

            //dataClasses.tblAlbums.SelectMany(album => album.ArtistID == getArtist.ArtistID).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<String> Albums
    {
        set
        {
            initialiseAlbums();
        }
        get
        {
            return this.albumList;
        }
    }
```

I was assuming that the Selected Item event would populate the second Combo Box but I was mistaken.

Comment: what happens when 2 or more artist have the same name? dont you need the id?

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `selectedArtist` before you do the `null` check?
I get `null` when I try `band.ArtistName == selectedArtist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to notify the view that the Albums property changed.
That's why you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and call the PropertyChanged event after building your albums list.

**For example**

```
public class Musics : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   private void initialiseAlbums()
   {
       if (selectedArtist != null)
       {
            //Your code
            OnPropertyChanged("Albums");
       }
    }
}
```

Its good workaround to use ObservableCollection<> instead of List<>.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the Observable collection. This is the answer I have successfully managed to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArtist, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

**Edit:**
And add a getter to the `SelectedArtist` property.

Comment: That's not worked as they still don't appear. Do I need to change anything on the second Combo Box property as well?

Comment: @framps, do you have any binding erros in your output window?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'SelectedArtist' value (type 'String') from '' (type 'ReadReviewsSelectViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedArtist; DataItem='ReadReviewsSelectViewModel' Is the error I'm getting

Comment: Thats beacause You don't have getter method in your SelectedArtist prop.

Answer (score 0):

> I was assuming that the Selected Item event would populate the second
>   Combo Box but I was mistaken

there is no selecteditem event. what you have is a SelectedItem Binding. and if you want your view to react to an action in your viewmodel you have to raise INotifyPropertyChanged.

so after your initialiseAlbums(); you have to call OnPropertyChanged("Albums"); at least.

ps: you can also create parentchildrelationobjects, makes such stuff more easier.

```
public class MyArtist
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public IList<Album> Albums {get;set}
}
```