# zIndex on ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, z-index

I need to have three combo boxes in a same data grid cell, like so:

```
<Grid Name="gridFormat_1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Margin="0, 5, 5, 5" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="monthsCB" DisplayMemberPath="MonthName" IsEnabled="False" Opacity="0" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="quartalsCB" DisplayMemberPath="QuartalNumber" IsEnabled="False" Opacity="0" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Name="yearsCB" DisplayMemberPath="Year" IsEnabled="False" Opacity="0" />
</Grid>
```

I want to be able to show/hide certain combo box at a given time. However, although Opacity and IsEnabled, do hide/show, disable/enable each combo box except the one I chose, I am not able to click on the combo boxes below the "yearsCB" since it is added last.

This means other two combo boxes do not receive mouse events.

I found that I should use some other WPF tag to wrap my combo boxes so I can switch the ZIndex on each of them.

Which tag would be that, which will allow me to manipulate Canvas or ZIndex?

Or is there some other better way to achieve this?

Comment: Would it be easier to update the DisplayMemberPath of a single combobox over trying to manage a z-order?  Isn't that essentially what you're going anyway?  Basically bind the DisplayMemberPath to a single property and update that property based on the business logic.

Comment: DataTriggers in wpf can solve your problems. Just describe a scenario, when do you wish the combobox to be visible/hidden.

Comment: @sous2817 I had just one combo box which I filled dynamically with months, quartals and years. I was working but it was mixed with the GUI. Now trying to use MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged but not sure how to bind single combo-box to a single property if the data type of the values in the combo-box change dynamically.

Comment: @Sham I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481109/how-to-bind-combobox-which-can-display-different-types-of-data-at-a-given-type

Comment: @Sham Can I fill up combo-box with different data if i choose different value in another combo-box?

Comment: Yes, you can..but the datatype has to be same.

Comment: we'd probably need more information to give you the best solution.  What are the rules for when you want to use the various options?  When is it appropriate to show "MonthName", "QuarterNumber", or "Year"?  Is there another combobox, or radio button or something?

Comment: @sous2817 already added this link, but ok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481109/how-to-bind-combobox-which-can-display-different-types-of-data-at-a-given-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050501/change-combobox-itemssource-based-on-another-combobox-selection or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661894/binding-combobox-to-another-combobox-in-wpf or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225286/bind-combo-box-based-on-another-combo-boxs-selected-item-mvvm-wpf  there are a lot of examples on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to set ZIndex, you can do it with attribute

```
Panel.ZIndex="1"
```

Higher the number, higher the item. Default ZIndex is 0.

In WPF you position elements inside their parent - in this case parent is Grid. [Grid class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid) is derived from [Panel class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel) and Panel has [ZIndex attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindexproperty).

If you want to switch between 3 comboboxes in one position you should change their Visiblity. Opacity only changes visual state and IsEnabled sets if element is enabled in UI.

For hidden combobox:

```
Visibility="Hidden"
```

For visible combobox:

```
Visibility="Visible"
```

Comment: The Visibility property did the job. Its working now. However I don't understand how to apply Panel.ZIndex since ComboBox doesn't contain property Panel.

Comment: Grid class is derived from Panel class and that contains ZIndex property. Combobox is in Grid hence you can set it similar to Grid.Row.

Comment: but i have to use top level Grid object to somehow change certain ComboBox ZIndex??

Comment: In your case Grid is top level object but more imporantly it is parent object of Comboboxes. You are positioning elements inside their parent - in this case it is Grid.